# Three.js Object3D custom vertex shader

Tags: three.js

I have a bunch of `Object3d` in the scene comprised of different meshes, e.g:

```
const object3d = new Object3D();
const bodyMaterial = new MeshLambertMaterial();
const bezelMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "0xffffff" });
const mesh = new Mesh(MeshFactory.mesh1, [ bodyMaterial, bezelMaterial ]);
const textLabel = TextFactory.createText("mesh1");
object3d.add(mesh, textLabel);
```

I'd like to move the `position` of the `object3d` on each frame,
currently doing that on the CPU:

```
render() {
    object3D.position = calcPosition(); // new Vector3
}
```

This is slow since I have hundreds of `Object3d` objects and each one should move separately.
So I'd like to write a `vertex shader` that moves the xyz on each frame but,
how do I write a shader for Object3D? (change position for all of it's meshes)?

Comment: Well this is exactly the question here, how to change a Group/Object3D position from a vertex shader? Since the shader position is for the mesh itself but the group contains many meshes

Comment: @shayy could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be going about things the wrong way...

But..
Here is a basic example of vertex displacement in a shader in three.js. 
Rotation is done in the render loop, but offset values are sent to the vertex shader.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    var uniforms = {
     xOffset: { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
      yOffset: { type: "f", value: 0.0 },
      zOffset: { type: "f", value: 0.0 }
    };
    var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
    var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
      {
        uniforms : uniforms,
        vertexShader : vertexShader,
        fragmentShader : fragmentShader
      });

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    
    // set up gui.
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
   gui.add(uniforms.xOffset, 'value', -500, 500).name('X Offset');
    gui.add(uniforms.yOffset, 'value', -500, 500).name('Y Offset');;
    gui.add(uniforms.zOffset, 'value', -500, 500).name('Z Offset');;

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r89/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/v0.6.2/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>


<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    uniform float xOffset;
    uniform float yOffset;
    uniform float zOffset;
    void main( void ) {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position + vec3(xOffset, yOffset, zOffset),1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is about multiple meshes in a single Object3D (or Group). How do I apply the offset to each mesh in the group? Currently in the render loop I just change the object3d.position. Could you also explain why "going about things the wrong way". What should be done differently?

Comment: loop over the meshes in the group and apply your offset, or if you are offsetting them all the same, apply the offset/position to the group itself. It seems none of us are really understanding the problem you are having, you may consider rewording your question.

Comment: I will leave my answer here in case it helps others

Comment: "loop over the meshes in the group and apply your offset" this is exactly the part that I'm looking to do on the GPU but I don't understand how to implement (apply the uniforms for each material in the meshes group?).

Comment: I do offset my group together and I'm unsure how to do that in the vertex shader. That's all (hopefully it's clearer now?)

Comment: You can't loop over multiple meshes in the shader, the shader only has access to the verticies of the mesh it is applied to. Maybe you want to combine all your meshes into a single mesh, and maybe make use of custom attributes in the shader. [HERE](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_custom_attributes.html) is an example of custom attributes